# matInput error design on dirty insted of on touched

Tags: angular, angular-material

angular material automatically colors the input when validation failed.

the error messages I can display with `*ngIf` the input is dirty, and if not - the error message not shown. the problem is the input itself turns red when **touched** is true and **not** when **dirty**.
how can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the behaviour with an "ErrorStateMatcher".

Wiki:
https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Example: 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/egqaopkeekx?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts